# How to use centralized SSIS dataflow and modularize SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Perhaps I am just too new to SSIS or have not really understood the basic concept. But I am a programmer who like to reuse as much as possible.

We have several SSIS projects that a have many things in common. E.g. we have programmed a flow to handle errors in specific way. Today we copy and paste this flow into each new project. It would be more convienient to refer to an external project/package so we can enhance the error handler centrally instead of copying it into each an every project. We think about something like the good old DLL concept.

The only ways we have found so far is to exchange data via DB tables or to use real external libraries. We would prefer to use as much built-in functionality as possible.

I have not found any literature or tutorial to modularize SSIS projects. Would be great to see the best practice here.

Comment: What is the error handling doing? Logging it? emailing? if the handler is just logging or notification, I suggest you remove this from the package and instead scan the built in SSIS package log after execution and action errors from there. Then your packages are self contained and your monitoring is self contained. Yes SSIS can get really repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reuse your C#/VB code written in Task Scripts of SSIS package even inside the same package.
You can put codes into a DLL (assembly) and put that into GAC.
Then you can add as reference into the project inside a Task Script and use your classes.
This is the only way to reuse code in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

On modularizing SSIS packages. You have several possibilities:

1. Pack defined actions into [SSIS Custom Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/task/developing-a-custom-task?view=sql-server-ver15) or Custom Transformation, which is a specific DLL, and then - use (refer) it in your SSIS packages. Have you changed your Custom Component and installed the updated version - next Package runs will use the updated logic. Complexity - high, you have to implement specific interfaces and develop UI to be used inside Visual Studio developer.
2. Code driven SSIS package generation. You define SSIS package logic in some code, and then use the code to generate SSIS packages. Either it could be done with [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-ver15) ManagedDTS class ([see examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically?view=sql-server-ver15)) or with [EzAPI](https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-ezapi/) classes which provide some abstraction over ManagedDTS, or with [BIML](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-biml-scripts-to-generate-ssis-packages/) script language.
   Complexity - med/high, you either have to generate SSIS package in C# after modelling it in Visual Studio, or in BIML script language.

Package generation is practical if you have multitude of similar packages. Otherwise it does not pay off; single package can be created in Visual Studio.

Why SSIS is not modular. My two cents - it was designed for non-programmers who can draw dataflows in designer. This can be done on ad-hoc basis, fast and with low personnel level. Besides, SSIS was created right after 2000's.
Nowdays, the approach changed, we are talking CI/CD etc, but SSIS concept stays the same.